# Three.js fiber / Drei - How to load an fbx model?

Tags: javascript, react-native, three.js, hook

Dear Stack Overflow folks,

I am using drei for react native / three.js fiber. I have followed the instruction at https://github.com/pmndrs/drei on how to load an fbx but cannot get it to work due to "Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:".

Could anyone point me to right direction how to do this.

````
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import React, { useDebugValue, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { Canvas, useFrame, useLoader } from 'react-three-fiber'

import { OrbitControls, Sky, useFBX, Loader } from '@react-three/drei'
import { debug } from 'react-native-reanimated';

useFBX('test/test1.fbx')

function SuzanneFBX() {
  let fbx = useFBX('test/test1.fbx')
  // wrap fbx in primitive.
  return <primitive object={fbx} dispose={null} />
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Canvas>
        <ambientLight />
        <pointLight position={[10, 10, 10]} />
        <OrbitControls />
        <Sky/>

      </Canvas>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    
      )
  );
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
}); ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're calling useFBX('test/test1.fbx') in global space. you can't use hooks outside of components.